# access multiple input attributes in angular 4

Tags: angular

Hi I have searched all over the internet but can not find an answer to this problem, so I have a huge table on one page and that table has approx `30-40` columns and certain columns have input based search filters something like this image:

[image: Table structure image]

and input defined like this:

```
<th><input type="text" appCustomSearch class="form-control width-0x" name="last_name" [searchTab]="'social'"/></th>
```

so basically I need to fetch 3/4 values using input fields:

- table to search
- column name within that table
- value to search.

but I can't find a way to do that easily and dynamically I have also tried writing my own directive but it only works on single input at a time I want a user to fill all the input fields he wants and then on button click it should filter results.
can access inputs via the form but not able to access data attributes or even "name" of the input field, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `ViewChildren` decorator for that. Start by creating a custom component for your input.

```
<input 
  type="text"
  appCustomSearch
  class="form-control width-0x"
  name="last_name"
  [searchTab]="'social'"
  #customSearch
/>
```

In your TS

```
@ViewChildren(CustomSearchDirective) inputs: QueryList<CustomSearchDirective>;
```

This will give a list of all of the inputs having the attribute `appCustomSearch`.